# viewPagerAdapter.getItem return fragment which activity is null

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    Log.d("ACTIVITY MAIN", "CREATED")
    setupViewPager(bottom_nav)
}

private fun setupViewPager(bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView) {
    val viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    val trainingFragment = TrainingFragment()
    val magicMileFragment = MagicMileFragment()
    val tournamentFragment = TournamentFragment()
    viewPagerAdapter.add(trainingFragment)
    viewPagerAdapter.add(magicMileFragment)
    viewPagerAdapter.add(tournamentFragment)

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
             R.id.magicMileFragment -> {
                 viewpager.currentItem = 1
                 if(viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1).activity == null)
                    Log.d("NULL ACTIVITY", "NULLL")
             }
             R.id.trainingFragment -> {
                 viewpager.currentItem = 0
             }
            R.id.tournamentFragment -> {
                viewpager.currentItem = 2
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

I have problem with my fragments inside `bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` with `viewPagerAdapter`.
After changing an orientation this condition: `if(viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1).activity == null)` is `true`.
I checked that activity remain null in all fragments inside `viewPagerAdapter`
I didn't attach code with setting an adapter because I don't think it's relevant.
Could you explain me why it's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `getItem` (*should*) always create a new instance of `Fragment` and does not commit them to transaction. `ViewPager` gets fragments from `instantiateItem` or `getItem` and commits them to transactions, and they will be attached to activity eventually.

So here's the snippet of `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem`:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    final long itemId = getItemId(position);

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = getItem(position);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
    }
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

`ViewPager` calls `instantiateItem` to get fragments, and within the method, it checks if the fragments exist, then return the fragments, otherwise it calls `getItem` to create new instance of them.

This explains why your activity is null on `getItem`. But if your `getItem` does not (*always*) return new instance of `Fragment`, then chances are your app will fail because the fragment's activity may not survive a configuration change, say a screen rotation.

Comment: I'm begginer with Android. Could you explain it in more details?

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation bro ! :D I've struggled with this for about 6 hours :(  and none of my friends couldn't actually help me.